# Package TideSDK app without sourcecode

Tags: tidesdk

I have developed a TideSDK app. I also packaged and installed it. Everything is working fine as expected. Only problem is, in the installation folder it also directly copy the source code (all of my html, js and css files inside the Resources folder). I do not want to distribute my app's source code. Is there any way to package a TideSDK app without revealing the source code? I hope there are some ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I found yesterday a tutorial how to make a single executable file with of TideSDK application.
You can do this by creating a sfx archive (self extracting archive).

Here is the link : http://coffeecone.com/post/36127491095/howto-single-exe-for-tidesdk

Comment: I just went through the article. It seems intelligent but still hack-ish solution. I would like to have standard legal (not sure if the word legal is applicable here, but I hope you understand what I mean) procedure. Also, that guy warned to use this procedure only for small apps and he also gave good reason for this. I have some quite larger projects to develop. So it seems that TideSDK is not right solution for me. But anyhow, thanks for your help.